# Writing Facebook apps in C#

Tags: c#, facebook

I am a C# developer and fancy the idea of writing a C# app or two to integrate with the Facebook API. I read from this page:

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/User:C_Sharp

that there's this Microsoft SDK for Facebook Platform that has binary assemblies that I can use to write my C# app. As a start, I want to try out the example mentioned on the above-mentioned page -- one that gets me a friend list.

The problem is: I am completely new to this Facebook development thing and I see I am going to need, at the very least, an API Key and some Facebook service Secret key or some such, to begin writing some code.

Do I also need a developer account? Where do I get all these things from?

Comment: I have an idea for your app. Find a way to permanently delete all your personal data once you close your account. Facebook seems to hang onto it forever, even after the account is closed.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Facebook Developers](http://www.facebook.com/developers/) application. With this application you can register a new application with Facebook and manage all [your applications](http://www.facebook.com/developers/#!/developers/apps.php) as well. Each registered application has associated API key and application secret.

To create a new application click on the [`+ Set Up New Application`](http://www.facebook.com/developers/#!/developers/createapp.php) button.

Note that if anyone gets a hold of the API key and the application secret, they can impersonate your application, so keep those safe.